# Error on deserializing a simple XML into a class object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfAddressDetails xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <AddressDetails>
    <DbServerName>2k8</DbServerName>
  </AddressDetails>
  <AddressDetails>
    <DbServerName>2k8R2D3</DbServerName>
  </AddressDetails>
</ArrayOfAddressDetails>
```

And I created two classes for it as follows:

```
public class AddressDetails
{
    public string DbServerName { get; set; }
}
```

}

and another class to hold a list of those:

```
   public class AddressList
    {
        public List<AddressDetails> addressList= new List<AddressDetails>() ;
    }
```

And this is how I am deserializng it:

```
    XmlSerializer deSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AddressList));
    TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\TEMP\MyXML.xml");
    Object obj = deSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
    AddressList adrsList = (AddressList)obj;
    reader.Close();
```

But on Deserialize method I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Rename "AddressList" to "ArrayOfAddressDetails". Or go to the xml and rename "ArrayOfAddressDetails" to "AddressList".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decorate:

- `AddressList` class with `XmlRoot` attribute like this `[XmlRoot("ArrayOfAddressDetails")]`
- `addressList` field with `XmlElement` attribute like this `[XmlElement("AddressDetails")]`

You have this at the end:

```
[XmlRoot("ArrayOfAddressDetails")]
public class AddressList
{
    [XmlElement("AddressDetails")]
    public List<AddressDetails> addressList = new List<AddressDetails>();
}
```